# How can i do autosize item height in listview for variable multirow long text with word wrap?

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

How can i do autosize item height in listview for variable multirow long text with word wrap? (Delphi Firemonkey Platform)

For example

[image]

and my listview

[image]

word wrap is ok via listview/itemappearance/item/text with (word wrap/true) and (trimming/none) options but autosize row height or fit height is not ok.

Comment: Your source code can help us to find an answer. Can you post it?

Comment: Hi there isn't code but forexample http://s1378.photobucket.com/user/moorkerg/media/listview_zpsf9qkojpb.png.html

Comment: and my listview http://s1378.photobucket.com/user/moorkerg/media/listviewn_zps3nrzl9oa.png.html

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I work with Delphi 10.3 and I create my own ListItems.
On ListView1UpdatingObjects when I create ListViewText with WardWrap:=True and fill it with text then do this

```
function GetTextHeight(const D: TListItemText; const Width: single; const 
Text: string): Integer;
var
  Layout: TTextLayout;
begin
  Layout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
  try
    Layout.BeginUpdate;
    try
      Layout.Font.Assign(D.Font);
      Layout.VerticalAlign := D.TextVertAlign;
      Layout.HorizontalAlign := D.TextAlign;
      Layout.WordWrap := D.WordWrap;
      Layout.Trimming := D.Trimming;
      Layout.MaxSize := TPointF.Create(Width, 
                      TTextLayout.MaxLayoutSize.Y);
      Layout.Text := Text;
    finally
      Layout.EndUpdate;
    end;
    Result := Round(Layout.Height);
    Layout.Text := 'm';
    Result := Result + Round(Layout.Height);
  finally
    Layout.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And call it like this

```
LText.Height := GetTextHeight(LText, LText.Width, LText.Text);
```